# How can I get values from dynamic TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

hello all 
i really need your help its my final project in university
i have to make matrix of text boxs that the user chosse the size of it 
but i dont know after i create it how do i refer to the textbox so i can do the calculation 
and how do i change the type . 
thats the code i made to get textbox at run time 
i hope you help me 
C# code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //TextBox tb = new TextBox();

        int y = 10;
         row = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        int col = row;
        //string []a = new string[row];
        int count = 0;
        int sum;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            int x = 10;

            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                 t = new TextBox();
                t.Size = new Size(50, 20);
                t.Name = "tb" + count;
                count++;
                t.Location = new Point(x, y);
                t.Visible = true;


                //t.GetType();
                //a[row] = t.Text;

                Controls.Add(t);
                x = x + 70;
                //t.Text =Convert.ToDecimal(t.Text);
                //Convert.ToDecimal(t.Text);
                if (t.Name == "tb1")
                    t.Text = "10";
            }
            y = y + 25;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a reference to each `TextBox` (you can store it in a two-dimension array, for example):

```
// Defined at the Form level
private TextBox[,] textBoxes = new TextBox[10, 10];

...

// When creating the TextBox
t = new TextBox();

...

// Store the reference
textBoxes[i, j] = t;

...
```

Later you can get the value:

```
var text = textBoxes[row, col].Text;
```

Comment: thank you very much i hope you update my page if i have other question

Answer (score 1):

Add a name to your newly inserted textboxes:

```
t.Name = "dynamicTextBox" + i.ToString();
```

After that, you can simply access it via its name:

```
this.Controls["dynamicTextBox0"].Text = "my text";
```

This prevents the need for an extra array to hold the textboxes you create dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

TextBox t = (TextBox)Controls["tb"+count.ToString()]

the name property of the contorl becomes the key in the control collection.

additionally you can check for Controls.ContainsKey("tb"+count.ToString()) for existence